# Spring Boot - Edit data

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I did the get, post and delete method. But now I'm suffering to do the put method.

My controller:

```
@RequestMapping("/teste/equipe/editar/{id}")
public String update(@RequestBody Team newTeam ,@PathVariable("id") Long id)
{
    Team team = teamService.findById(id);
    
    team.setName(newTeam.getName());
    team.setName(newTeam.getRole());
    teamService.save(team);

    return "redirect:/teste/equipe";
}
```

HTML:

```
<form action="/teste/equipe/editar/{id}" method="PUT">
    <input type="text" th:field="${team.name}" placeholder="Nome">
    
    <br>

    <input type="text" th:field="${team.role}" placeholder="Função">

    <button>
        Enviar
    </button>
</form>
```

Error:
[image]

Comment: You do a redirect to: `return "redirect:/teste/equipe";`

Where is the `@RequestMapping`|`@PutMapping` for `/teste/equipe`?

Comment: I didn't post the entire controller code, I just put the put method

Comment: Also note if you use @RequestMapping its generally considered a security risk since you're enabling any type of request to pass through your system which can lead to attempting to handle unexpected requests (OPTIONS/HEAD/Etc) Try instead to stick with `@GetMapping`, `@PutMapping`, `@PostMapping`, etc. and you'll have only allowed certain request types to work.

Comment: True, thanks for the remark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not certain this helps but the error on the whitelabel error page states:

`Number Format Exception for input` `{id}`

Seems like you're expecting {id} in your form:

```html
<form action="/teste/equipe/editar/****{id}****" method="PUT">
```

to be interpolated with an actual ID. Should it instead be:

```html
<form action="/teste/equipe/editar/${id}" method="PUT">
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that was it. Lacked a little attention kkkk